# How to log WHAT was not found on error 404 with PHP

Tags: php, custom-error-pages

Excuse me if this question is on the wrong community. If this is treu, where do I post this question. I can not find any answer to this.

I'm trying to capture and record to a file, WHICH page/file the user provided in the link and was not found, and therefore called 404 error page.

Example, if someone types "http://example.com/indx.html" by wrong typing index, then Apache/Nginx will show the 404 error page.
If I define `ErrorDocument 404 /errosHtml/php404.php` in `.htaccess`, the page php404.php will be displayed.

How can I identify, in `php404.php`, which page was requested and not found.
I would like to log this to a file and also show the error to the user. For example:
`<p>The file [indx.html] does not exist on this server. Did you type it wrong?`

I tried the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable, but it shows `php404.php`.

I googled a lot, but there was no response for this.

Thanks in advance.

Best

Comment: This information is almost certainly already being logged by your web browser, check your Apache/Nginx config to locate the correct file.

Comment: Check this to see whether it helps: [How to get .htaccess to attach REQUEST\_URI to 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533020/how-to-get-htaccess-to-attach-request-uri-to-404-page)

Comment: In nginx it is configured by `access_log` directive.

Comment: I would like to identify it in PHP error manipulation and write a record into data base for future use.

Answer (score 0):

I made a lot of tests until I found the solution:

```
<h1>404</h1>
<?php 
    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $wrongFileOrDir = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $ErrorDocumentScript = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    echo("You called [".$host."<b>".$wrongFileOrDir."</b>]. that do no exists. Verify if you not mistyped<<br>");
    echo($ErrorDocumentScript);
 ?>
```

I hope this can help someone.
Best